# How should I go about reading stacked spreadsheets?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have been assigned to read a .HDR file that is formatted as a stack of small spreadsheets. The format is like this:

```
* Block title 1
* column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | ... | column n
data 1,1 | data 1,2 | data 1,3 | ... | data 1,n
data 2,1 | data 2,2 | data 2,3 | ... | data 2,n
data 3,1 | data 3,2 | data 3,3 | ... | data 3,n
   ...   |    ...   |    ...   | ... |    ...
data n,1 | data n,2 | data n,3 | ... | data n,n
*
* Block title 2
* column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | ... | column n
data 1,1 | data 1,2 | data 1,3 | ... | data 1,n
data 2,1 | data 2,2 | data 2,3 | ... | data 2,n
data 3,1 | data 3,2 | data 3,3 | ... | data 3,n
   ...   |    ...   |    ...   | ... |    ...
data n,1 | data n,2 | data n,3 | ... | data n,n
*
```

Note that the columns have different names in each block.

This is generally the format, but there are exceptions as well. Sometimes the data is formatted like this:

```
* Block title 1
* column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | ... | column n
data 1,1 | data 1,2 | data 1,3 | ... | data 1,n
data 2,1 | data 2,2 | data 2,3 | ... | data 2,n
data 3,1 | data 3,2 | data 3,3 | ... | data 3,n
   ...   |    ...   |    ...   | ... |    ...
data n,1 | data n,2 | data n,3 | ... | data n,n
* Block title 1 (this is the same title as above)
data 1,1 | data 1,2 | data 1,3 | ... | data 1,n
data 2,1 | data 2,2 | data 2,3 | ... | data 2,n
data 3,1 | data 3,2 | data 3,3 | ... | data 3,n
   ...   |    ...   |    ...   | ... |    ...
data n,1 | data n,2 | data n,3 | ... | data n,n
*
```

Note the absence of column names.

Ideally, I'd like to use csv.Dictreader or pandas or something to process this, but I'm not sure how. I need to turn each mini-spreadsheet into a dictionary and then nest them in another dictionary. How would you approach this problem? (Note: I am writing this in Python 2.7.)

Comment: pandas text readers allow you skip rows in the "header" and "footer"

Comment: @PaulH Can you elaborate on this? I'm not sure what specifically you're addressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pandas' `pd.read_table()` to read the first column (up to the `|` if any).  Then use something like this to find the separator rows:

```
seps = np.where(df.str.startswith('*'))
```

Now you have an array of row indexes where separators exist.  Next, open the file yourself and read it piece by piece, roughly like this:

```
skiprows=0
with open(path) as rf:
    for sep in seps:
        pd.read_table(rf, nrows=sep-skiprows, skiprows=skiprows)
        skiprows += sep
```

In other words, you do a single pass to figure out the file layout, then a second pass to read the DataFrames.